# PMD can't find rule UseSingleton

Tags: java, eclipse, pmd

For some weird reason PMD is giving this error:

```
An internal error occurred during: "ReviewCode".
    Unable to find referenced rule UseSingleton; perhaps the rule name is mispelled?
```

this is how this rule is declared in my ruleset.xml:

```
   <rule ref="rulesets/java/design.xml/UseSingleton"/>
```

I'm using Eclipse Kepler with 4.0.6 PMD plugin version. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See also the answer on the bug report [#1339](https://sourceforge.net/p/pmd/bugs/1339/) and the [changelog for 5.3.1](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-5.3.1/overview/changelog.html):

> Language Java, ruleset design.xml: The rule “UseSingleton” has been renamed to “UseUtilityClass”. See also bugs #1059 and #1339.

This is fixed with PMD 5.3.1 and later.

For the time being, you'll need to manually fix the ruleset file and replace `UseSingleton` with `UseUtilityClass`. I'd suggest to shutdown eclipse, locate the ruleset.xml file in your workspace, change it, and start eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to use config for PMD >= 5.0. For lower versions you need to remove `java/` from rule reference:

```
<rule ref="rulesets/design.xml/UseSingleton"/>
```

From PMD 5.0 release notes:

> This version of PMD breaks API compatibility with prior versions of PMD, as well as RuleSet XML compatibility. Also the maven coordinates (groupId) have been changed. The decision to break compatibility, allows PMD
>   internals and code organization to be improved to better handle additional
>   languages.